# Bound on the tail of a Poisson branching process

Tags: random-graphs, probabilistic-method

I'm trying to understand this argument from "The Probabilsitic Method" book:

Let $T_c$ be the time of extinction for a Poisson branching process with parameter $c$. The authors prove that $$P[T_c=k] = \frac{e^{-ck}(ck)^{k-1} }  {k!}  .$$

From this they argue that, by Stirling's approximation, $$P[T_c = k] \sim \frac{1}{2 \pi}k^{-3/2}c^{-1}(ce^{1-c})^k.$$

If we assume $c<1$, then $ce^{1-c}<1$ and $P[T_c=k]$ approaches $0$ at exponential speed.

This is where I get lost: This gives a bound on the tail distribution: $P[T_c \ge u] < e^{-u(\alpha +o(1))},$ where $\alpha = c-1-\ln c > 0$.

Where does this come from? Is it some application of the Chernoff bound (if so, which version?), or is it more elementary than that?

Answer (score 1):

$$P(T_c \ge u) = \sum_{k=u}^\infty P(T_c=k)
\le \frac{1}{2\pi} u^{-3/2} c^{-1} \sum_{k=u}^\infty (c e^{1-c})^k
= \frac{1}{2\pi} u^{-3/2} c^{-1} \frac{1}{1-ce^{1-c}} \cdot(c e^{1-c})^u.$$
The last term is
$$(ce^{1-c})^u = e^{-u\alpha}$$
with $\alpha := c-1-\ln c$.
The logarithm of the other terms is
$$\ln \left(\frac{1}{2\pi} u^{-3/2} c^{-1} \frac{1}{1-ce^{1-c}}\right)
= -\frac{3}{2} \ln u + C_c = o(u)$$
where $C_c = \ln\left(\frac{1}{2\pi} c^{-1} \frac{1}{1-ce^{1-c}}\right)$.
Exponentiating both sides yields
$$\frac{1}{2\pi} u^{-3/2} c^{-1} \frac{1}{1-ce^{1-c}} = e^{-u o(1)}.$$